# Solving systems of equations in two variables - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just start to learn python and learned about variables, input and basic math.

I been asked to write a mathematical exercise which has the parameters:

> ax+by=c, dx+ey=f
>
> a, b, c, d,e, f - the user input and than the program result and write
>   the answear for x, y

I did:

```
number1 = float(input('Insert a number1: '))

number2 = float(input('Insert a number2: '))

number3 = float(input('Insert a number3: '))

number4 = float(input('Insert a number4: '))

number5 = float(input('Insert a number:5 '))

number6 = float(input('Insert a number6: '))
```

I don't how to write an equation with two variables

```
x=number1+2.5*number2-number3 #(it should be looked like ax+by=c)

y=number5+2.5*number6-number4
```

ax+by=c AND dx+ey=f ==> x=(-by+ey-f+c)(a-d)

I also don't know why I can't write the variable inside print:

```
print('the value of x, y is') print((x))
```

Comment: I suggest using the names a,b,c,d,e,f instead of number1,number2 etc to make it more clear that they are going to be used in the formula.

Comment: Look for string interpolation/formatting in Python.

Comment: but how I write x and y? do I writing differently the equation ax+by=c to something like x = (c-by)/a? I mean how the program know to solve 2 equation?

Comment: No, plain Python doesn't know how to solve a pair of [simultaneous linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) like that (although there are various 3rd-party modules that can do that). Do you know how to solve such equations by hand? If so, you can write Python code that performs the same procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you must think in a way to solve a equation with 2 variables using a programming language, it's not so straightforward if you're not familiar with programming.

Think about the steps you have to take to solve that manually first and then try to implement that using Python, I'll try to help you with some guiding:

1- Find a number to multiply one of the equations so that you can "remove" one of the variables.

2- Sum both of the equations (forget about the variables for now, work only with their coefficients)

3- After summing both equations and storing the "new_coefficient" values and assuming you removed `x` you should have something like: `((e*step_1_number)+b)*y = f*step_1_number + c`

4- With the previous step you'll be able to find your `y` value, after that it's pretty easy to find the `x` value.

I managed to do this using Python but I don't think it's going to be useful for you if I just post my code, try to work something out yourself, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

You can write the above equations in `matrix` form.

[image: writing in matrix form]

You can find answer to `(x,y)` easily with this method. You just have to solve this matrix equation.

[image: solution to x and y]

You can find the answer using `numpy`. (Or you just have to implement matrix inverse and multiplication your own)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[a, b], [d, e]])
B = np.array([[c], [f]])
print(np.linalg.inv(A) @ B)
```

Comment: I don't think I can to solve it in a way that different from what my teacher teached us...it even not a faction that I know or close to one.